# Date control for month year format not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

am developing a cross browser application but am having problems with the date control(month year format).

the control is placed in a table together with other controls.
this is how am creating my control

```
  table_html = '<td style="min-width: 200px;"><input name="' + control_id + '" id="' + control_id + '" value="' + row_val + '" type="month"></td>';
```

when i run it on firefox version 24 the control is displayed as a normal text box control allowing users to enter any value...when i run it on chrome it works fine.

Any assistance on how it will work fine on the Firefox will be highly regarded and appreciated. plugins are also accepted.

regards,
Jose

Comment: please check whether it is compatible with your firebox version or not at http://html5test.com/

Comment: it is not compatible with firebox 24

Answer (score 0):

I had a smilair problem with inputting dates on different browsers.
I ended up using DateBox as it worked on all the browsers I was aiming at.

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/install.html

It could be a solution for you, even though it is not the one you seem to be looking for.